# Can we get rid of set_session in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to migrate code from Tensorflow 1.13 to Tensorflow 2.0 and I'm having issues with the session declaration step.

For now, I replaced `tf.keras.backend.set_session` by `tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session`.

```py
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()

config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
if self._gpu_fraction:
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = self._gpu_fraction
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

The code is running but I get a warning:
`The name tf.keras.backend.set_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session instead.`

I understood that sessions evolved a lot with Tensorflow 2 but I'm not sure if I can/should get rid of this `set_session`.
I'm also not sure about the warning: is `tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session` calling the old `tf.keras.backend.set_session`?

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!